# Async post - handling a reply

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to upload a list of images. I have the images stored in an array (called images).

I have the previews displayed on the screen.

What I want to do is upload them sequentially, and as they complete their upload, I want to set a flag. When this flag is set (thanks to the power of Knockout), the image disappears from the list.

However, I think due to the async nature of the post command .. I'm not achieving the desired results.

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < self.images().length; i++) {
  var photo = self.images()[i];
  var thisItem = photo;
  var object = JSON.stringify({
    Image: thisItem.Image,
    AlbumID: albumId,
    Filesize: thisItem.Filesize,
    Filetype: thisItem.Filetype,
    Description: thisItem.Description,
    UniqueID: thisItem.UniqueID
  });
  var uri = "/api/Photo/Upload";
  $.post({
    url: uri,
    contentType: "application/json"
  }, object).done(function(data) {
    if(data.IsSuccess) {
      photo.Status(1);
    }
  }).fail(function() {
    // Handle here
  }).always(function() {
    remainingImages = remainingImages - 1;
    if(remainingImages == 0) self.isUploading(false);
  });
}
self.isUploading(false);
```

But I think what's happening is that the for loop ends before all the posts have received a reply. Because online one image is removed.

I tried with a `async: false` ajax post, but that locked up the screen and then they all disappeared.

I thought the 'done' method would only execute once the post is completed, but I think the whole method just ends once the post commands have been sent, and then I never get the `done`.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do... Set each image's status once the post gets a reply?

Comment: Your, `for` loop won't wait till you get all the promises, because it will execute synchronously. And since, (_if i am not wrong_) you are handling the upload of the images with a single variable `self.isUploading`, it will overwrite the intended value. What I think would be a good approach is to have a variable associated with each image that will track whether that was uploaded or not. Then you can filter out from the `images` array only those images that are not uploaded yet...

Comment: Thanks @gkb - that's now what I'm trying to do. The Image object has a 'Status' number, which I am trying to set. ("photo.Status(1);)", but it still seems like the loop completes too early. Does the "Done" only fire once the api call is completed? I think I see what you mean though, but not sure how to check if the upload is complete based on the number of images with a status of 0 (0 = pending, 1 = uploaded).

Comment: I am not very sure of how it is done using pure JavaScript, but if going for a library seems feasible to you..you might want to look at `Q.js` here - https://github.com/kriskowal/q.. and write a function to upload _a single image_, then call this function for each uploaded image and inside of the `.then` handler of your group function(like `Q.all` https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination), you can update the statuses of images uploaded.....

Comment: as you seem to be using jquery already - I would look into `jQuery.map` to map the images array? to promises, and using `jQuery.map` to wait for them all to complete - perhaps something like - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/0msntL2h/

Comment: Your `photo.Status` is overwritten with the last value of `self.images`. That's why when you change the value of `photo.Status`, only one image is removed. So don't use synchronous loops here, try JaromandaX's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are losing the reference you think you have to each `photo` object because the loop finishes before your AJAX calls return, so that when they do return, `photo` is a reference to the last item in `self.images()`.

What we need to do to solve this is to create a *new* scope for each iteration of the loop and each of those scopes will have its own reference to a particular `photo`. JavaScript has function scopes, so we can achieve our goal by passing each `photo` to a function. I will use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) as an example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.images().length; i++) {
    var photo = self.images()[i];
    (function (thisItem) {
        /* Everything else from within your for loop goes here. */
        /* Note: the done handler must reference `thisItem`, not `photo`. */
    })(photo);
}
```

Note that you should remove `self.isUploading(false);` from the last line. This should not be set to false until all of the POST requests have returned.

I have created a functioning fiddle that you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vgsh2jh8/).

However, this solution will not perform the POST requests "sequentially". I am not sure why you would want to wait for one POST to return before sending the next as this will only increase the time the user must wait. But for the sake of completeness, I will explain how to do it.

To fire a POST after the previous POST returns you will need to remove the for loop. You will need a way to call the next POST in the `always` handler of the previous POST. This is a good candidate for a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) function.

In my solution, I use an `index` to track which item from `images` was last POSTed. I recursively call the function to perform the POST on the next item in `images` until we have POSTed all items in `images`. The following code replaces the for loop:

```
(function postNextImage (index) {
    var photo = self.images()[i];
    var thisItem = photo;
    var object = JSON.stringify({
        Image: thisItem.Image,
        AlbumID: albumId,
        Filesize: thisItem.Filesize,
        Filetype: thisItem.Filetype,
        Description: thisItem.Description,
        UniqueID: thisItem.UniqueID
    });

    var uri = "/api/Photo/Upload";

    $.post({
        url: uri,
        contentType: "application/json"
    }, object)
    .done(function (data) {
        if(data.IsSuccess) {
            thisItem.Status(1);
        }
    })
    .fail(function () {
        // Handle here
    })
    .always(function () {
        if (index < (self.images().length - 1)) {
            index += 1;
            postNextImage(index);
        } else {
            self.isUploading(false);
        }
    });

})(0);
```

I have created a fiddle of this solution also, and it can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/kf7k4gkv/).

Comment: Great answer, i'm just only missing why your Fiddle isn't working with jQuery versions below 2.2.0 ?

Comment: It's because that overload of `$.post` that takes a `settings` object as first param, and which I copied directly from your question, was not introduced until jQuery 2.2. See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-settings. I have updated the first fiddle to be compatible with jQuery < 2.2: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vgsh2jh8/3/

Comment: Incredible answer! I'll try this in the morning. Thanks so much for your efforts.

Comment: @76484 - With regards, "POST requests "sequentially"" - this was a poor word used by me. What I meant was each post needs to be handled separately, and I seemed to ber losing data in my method. Posting loads at the same type asynchronously - would be far better.

Comment: This has achieved the exact result I was looking for. Thanks very much! I've learnt a lot!